# IphoneX simulator closing popovers when I interact with them

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, uipopovercontroller, iphone-x

I'm having a problem with the iPhone X simulator in Xcode behaving differently to other simulators.

What I'm trying to do it click on a view which brings up a UIPicker.  When a date is selected and the user clicks ok the popover disappears and a label in the view is updated with the string of what was selected.  This is working on the 2 physical devices I'm using (iPhone6 plus and iPad).  It's also working in simulators for iPhone 5 and 8.  However when I try the iPhoneX it doesn't work.

As soon as the user the taps the picker or moves it it fades of the screen and nothing gets updated.  As I don't have a physical iPhoneX to test with I don't know if this is just a simulator issue or if it will also happen on an actual device.  Is this just a simulator issue?  How can I fix this?  Will this also happen on an actual device?

Below is the function I'm using to display the custom popover containing the picker view.

```
/// When the view is tapped it will display user options and then update the label in the view.
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - box: LabelAndWhiteBarView is my own custom UIView for this project.
///     - strings: array of strings to be displayed by the picker
func displayStringPicker(box: LabelAndWhiteBarView, strings: [String]){

    // Custom viewcontroller containing a UIPickerView, title UILabel and a cancel and OK UIButton.
    let floatingPickerViewController:FloatingPickerViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "FloatingPickerStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()! as! FloatingPickerViewController

    floatingPickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    floatingPickerViewController.preferredContentSize = defaultPickerSize  // set elsewhere so it doesnt cover the whole screen

    //Adds a blank string in front of each array so the user can always pick and empty option
    var stringsWithBlankFirstOption = strings
    stringsWithBlankFirstOption.insert("", at: 0)
    floatingPickerViewController.stringArray = stringsWithBlankFirstOption
    //tells the picker view which view to update
    floatingPickerViewController.senderBox = box
    floatingPickerViewController.delegate = self
    floatingPickerViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    floatingPickerViewController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let popoverMenuViewController = floatingPickerViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue:0) // removed the arrow thats defauls on a popover
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = self.view

    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: self.view.frame.width,
        height: self.view.frame.height)

    floatingPickerViewController.dismissBlock = {

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    present(
        floatingPickerViewController,
        animated: false,
        completion: nil)

    /// set the picker to preselect what was already selected
    let indexOfSelectedItem = floatingPickerViewController.stringArray.index(of: box.displayLabel.text ?? "") ?? 0

    //pre selects the last selected string
    floatingPickerViewController.numberPicker.selectRow(indexOfSelectedItem, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: I have the same on iPad simulator. you?

Comment: Yes, I was seeing the problem in simulator.